# Where is my badge...? :-S

Tags: bug

I was looking forward to my `Strunk & White` (funny: not even my dictionary knows that word...) badge. It says: "Edited 80 posts"

The [users list](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users?page=2&tab=editors&filter=all) says I have 100+. Is that limited to certain kinds of edits?

Comment: Certain badges get applied every 30 mins or so, some are only daily!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a word, it's the authors of [The Elements of Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style).

Besides what slm said, the users page counts all edits. Strunk & White (and Copy Editor) don't count edits to your own posts or tag edits, and each post only counts once no matter how many times you edit it. If you go to a [review queue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) and hover over the progress bar, it will show your progress towards Copy Editor, so you can see how close you are to 80 edits:

http://so.mrozekma.com/unix-review-badge-progress.png

Comment: You sure tags edits doesn't count? Tag edits are counted now as normal edits.

Comment: @Braiam According to [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84767/145982) they don't, but it might've changed I guess